# Python _tkinter.TclError from root.mainloop() after calling root.destroy()

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, while-loop

Why do I get an error with my tkinter `mainloop()` about a invalid command name `canvas`?  I am creating an AI board game, and I created a main loop. I use 2 lists for my checker id's, `black_id`, and `white_id`, just not portrayed here:

```
def main_game_AI():
    print("Read the README file first to learn how to move.")
    move = input("What do you move?:")
    checker_move = int(move)
    where = input("What direction will you move?:")
    canvas.move(black_id[checker_move],-23,-50)
    print("Robot: OOOOOOoooooh!! Tricky decision! I play:")
    canvas.move(white_id[3], -23,50)
    white3 = 18   
print("We start with the",first_side,"side.")
while gameOn == True:
    main_game_AI()
    root.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
```

In my loop, `main_game_AI()` runs, then I run the `root.mainloop()` for the tkinter gui to work. But I must use `root.destroy()`, so the loop continues. This works well for the first iteration. But when I put in the test inputs for the second iteration, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chineseCheckersAI.py", line 86, in <module>
    main_game_AI()
  File "chineseCheckersAI.py", line 77, in main_game_AI
    canvas.move(black_id[checker_move],-23,-50)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2588, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call `mainloop` in a loop? It should be called exactly once for the life of the program. You can't call it again once the window has been destroyed.

Comment: Yes, but then, i can't update the canvas.